# How to fix here document throwing error instead of creating file?

Tags: bash

Why does the following here document throw error instead of creating `~/Desktop/test.sh`?

> sed: /first_names.txt: No such file or directory

```sh
cat << EOF > ~/Desktop/test.sh
#! /bin/bash

set -e

first_name=`sed "$(jot -r 1 1 2048)q;d" $dirname/first_names.txt | sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z]//g'`

echo #first_name
EOF
```

Comment: the contents of heredoc are expanded before being written to `test.sh`. You need to quote the heredoc to avoid this expansion - `'EOF'`

Comment: `$dirname` is empty and so `$dirname/first_names` is reduced to `/first_names` while writing the script. I assume, that the file does not exists in the root directory.

Comment: @Inian Thanks! Didn’t know heredoc’s were expanded. Please submit an answer.